# How to give Flash message a custom css class in cake 3

Tags: cakephp, flash-message

I want to give a Flash message a custom css class in Cakephp 3, there is my function in my (edit in this case) controller:

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('personalizado');
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success('Utilizador editado com sucesso.', 'default', ['class' => 'alert alert-success']);
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Erro ao apagar utilizador, por favor tente de novo.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

I added the custom css claas in this line:

```
$this->Flash->success('Utilizador editado com sucesso.', 'default', ['class' => 'alert alert-success']);
```

but is not working, thanks in advance.

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description! Even if the problem might be obvious for people that know the CakePHP internals, please always be as specific as possible as to what _exactly_ happens, and what you'd expect to happen instead. Show the data that you are working with, the context, your debugging attempts, and possible errors. Often the problem solves itself when collecting these information.

Comment: Thanks for your explannation, next time i will be more specific, in this case the css class is not loaded, i will try the answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// In your Controller
$this->Flash->success('The user has been saved', [
    'params' => [
        'class' => 'alert alert-success'
    ]
]);

// In your View
<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>

<!-- In src/Template/Element/Flash/success.ctp -->
<div class="<?= h($params['class']) ?>">
    <?= h($message) ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because that's not how it is supposed to work. Don't just throw in stuff and hope for the best, read the documentation first to figure out how things are ment to be done!

There simply is no `class` option.

**[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Flash > Setting Flash Messages](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/flash.html#setting-flash-messages)**

If you want to set a specific class for the success flash message, then you have to modify the flash message element that lives in `src/Template/Element/Flash/success.ctp`, similar to as shown in the linked docs.

You can use the `params` option to pass custom options and use them in your elements if you want to define things on controller level.

Comment: Thank you for your contribuition, next time i will do the staff you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I´m suppose you want load alert with boostrap class

If customizate success flash message you should go to **src/Template/Flash/success.ctp**

and add your classes

```
<div class="alert alert-success" onclick="this.classList.add('hidden')">
  <strong><?= __('Success') ?>!</strong> <?= h($message) ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is works for me.

Go to **src/Template/Element/**
Create directory file called "**Flash**"
Put your **success.ctp** and **error.ctp** template in that directory file. 
So you have 2 files called **success.ctp** and **error.ctp** in directory **src/Template/Element/Flash/**

put this script in your **src/Template/Element/Flash/success.ctp**

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <?= strip_tags($message, '<br>') ?>
</div>
```

also, put this script in your **src/Template/Element/Flash/error.ctp**

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <?= strip_tags($message, '<br>') ?>
</div>
```

And next, add this flash script function in your **Controller**

```
$this->Flash->error(__("Your error message"));
return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
```

for your error flash message or this bellow

```
$this->Flash->success(__("Your successed message"));
return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
```

for your successed flash message.
Then, in your **view.ctp** add this script bellow

```
<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
```

Dont forget to load FlashComponent in your AppController.php first.

**More detail setting is in [this](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/flash.html#setting-flash-messages) page. Check it out.**